# How to update the DOM after a long HTTP request without anything to do with $scope in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

In Angular, we can use $apply or $digest to update the DOM. However, I want to practice coding without using $scope so as to be easier to adapt to Angular 2 but I don't know how to update the DOM followed by a HTTP request!!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921058/alternative-to-scope-in-angularjs-2-0 for more information. Actually in angular1, using $apply or $digest is a bad practice. Dunno about angular2

Comment: most things will trigger a $digest on their own.. 
The case where I could see this needing to be done would be you are storing values in a service which is being referenced in your controller.
Maybe you could post the specific example.

Comment: Also in this blog http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/ the team said "t's too soon to start building anything with 2.0 code -- we're still in the very early stages of building out the project." So i woudn't worry that much about no using scope. $scope will exist but in a different way. Anyway it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `$scope` to bridge between your controller and view, you may use `controller as` syntax:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <p>Hello {{main.name}}!</p>
</body>
```

In  your controller, it's good practice to bind `this` to `self` or some other var you will recognize so you can reference them later on.  You can use `this` but it can get confusing and complicated to work with if you don't bind it to a var.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = 'test'
});
```

I'm not sure that this pattern will get you used to angular 2, but it is considered by some as a better way to code in angular.

If for some reason you NEED to fire a $digest, I think the generally accepted hacky way is to run a $timeout when you need to fire the $digest.  $timeout inherently calls one.

```
$timeout(function(){},0);
```

I would probably just set up a $watch though, if I needed to keep an eye on some changing data.

Comment: this work perfectly but if the binding is in a callback of a request, it doesn't a change