# Angular (2+) Singleton services for use in other modules

Tags: angularjs, singleton, angular-services

Im trying to work out what's the best way to achieve adding a singleton service to a 'core module' and consuming that service from a component within another module without creating a new instance of the service, as follows:

`CoreModule ----- AppModule (imports CoreModule) ----- AppRoutingModule
    |                |
CacheService     SubModule (loaded from AppRoutingModule with 'loadChildren:')
                     |
                 SubComponent (loaded from SubRoutingModule, needs to use CacheService)`

Note: This is a little different to simply using a singleton service shared by components belonging to the AppModule as I would like sub-modules to also utilise that service. According to the docs Services aren't inherited through modules?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a singleton service in Angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198785/how-do-i-create-a-singleton-service-in-angular-2)

Comment: Even the same rule for Sub-Modules too...

Comment: Isn't it??? @JonRowley

Comment: So I think I have it solved. Basically we need to create a static forRoot method in the CoreModule and then import that within the AppModule using CoreModule.forRoot(); This provides the singleton service for lazy loaded Modules.

Comment: I hope you can post your answer brief so that question would be answered. @JonRowley