# How to keep the login token so that it can be used by other components?

Tags: angular

Let's say, I make a post request to create my token.

```
public tokenInfo: TokenInfo;

public login(creds){
   return this.http.post<TokenInfo>(this.baseUrl + "Account/CreateToken", creds)
          .map(res =>{
                this.tokenInfo = res;  
                return true;                      
          })
  }
```

I get back my token and the expiration date. something like:

`{token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ...", expiration: "2017-12-04T03:40:55Z"}`

How do I keep it around so that other component can take advantage of it? The first thing that comes to mind is to `display the name of the logged user` at the left corner of the menu bar and hide the `Login` item.

Thanks for helping

Comment: localStorage? Redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a service for this purpose:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authToken: TokenInfo;

  public login(creds) {
    // You could store the auth token in local storage here instead.
    return this.http.post('/login').subscribe((res) => this.authToken = res);
  }

  public getAuthToken() {
    return this.authToken;
  }
}

export class YourComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  login() { 
    this.authService.login({ /* Your credentials. */ });
  }

  displayToken() {
     alert(this.authService.getAuthToken());
  }
}
```

Comment: So, do you mean that `AuthService ` won't be re-created each time the a new component is created? I really like this idea.

Comment: It won't be re-created if you're injecting the service in the providers definition of your app.module file.

Have a look at this for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/36198785/3713362

Answer (score 1):

You can save your token in the web storage like this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
```

And you can get it later like this:

```
window.localStorage.getItem('token');
```