# Why is constructor call each time after injection of service?

Tags: angular, angular6

I use Angular 2. I use singleton service `@NgModule({})` in section providers: `['MenuService']` I use `MenuService`.

**MenuService** looks as:
@Injectable()

```
export class MenuService {

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private i18nService: I18nService) { console.log('Called'); }
}
```

There are two components where I inject this service:

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  constructor(private menuService: MenuService) {}
}

export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private menuService: MenuService) {}
}
```

I see `console.log('Called');` twice, why is it called repeatly?

Comment: Are the two components and the service is in the same module?

Comment: Have you provided the service in more than one place?

Comment: Yes, two components are determined in the same module: `Core.module` in section declarations:  `declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ]`

Comment: Yes,  I provide it in two components, I said this above

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A service will always run its constructor when injected in a component, it has to set the fields/props of the service. So it is not weird behaviour at all. The injected interfaces 'act' as 2 objects.

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: Well it is fairly obvious, one has to have an instance of a service first before you can use it, therefore it has to be instantiated (aka constructor will be called)

Comment: Why would it be called twice if it is a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

> There are two ways to make a service a singleton in Angular:
>
> - Declare that the service should be provided in the application root.
> - Include the service in the AppModule or in a module that is only       imported by the AppModule.
>
> Beginning with Angular 6.0, the preferred way to create a singleton
>   services is to specify on the service that it should be provided in
>   the application root. This is done by setting `providedIn` to root on
>   the service's `@Injectable` decorator
>
> ```
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Injectable({
>   providedIn: 'root',
> })
> export class UserService {
> }
> ```

taken from [Angular official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

Comment: What about Angular 2?

Comment: Did you go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198785/how-do-i-create-a-singleton-service-in-angular-2/36200020)

Comment: Invalid number of arguments in Angular 2 if to do: `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})`

Comment: Yeah you cant use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'})` in angular 2. Only after angular 6.0 you can use this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, injected service `constructors` are called by component immediately when they are initialized.

```
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private menuService: MenuService) {}
}
```

is equivalent of doing

```
private menuService: MenuService;
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor() {
      this.menuService = new MenuService(params...);
  }
}
```

So basically, `DI` eliminates the need of creating the objects explicitly as shown in second method.

*`DI` is helpful when `MenuService` constructor is expecting some parameters and you are not sure what to send.*

Comment: But OP says it's a singleton?