# Why is my constructor in my service called just once?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am little confused. Reading this stackoverflow question.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395830/why-is-constructor-call-each-time-after-injection-of-service
```

Here for older version of angular they say that constructor from service is called each time it is initialized. I am using angular version 10 and by me is called just once. So my question is if anybody knows why ?

The test code that i have are two components.In their constructor's is injected the testService.
And in the constructor from the testService i have just console log statement.

**TEST SERVICE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
  constructor() { console.log('constructor called')};
}
```

**HOME COMPONENT**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) { };
}
```

**LAYOUT COMPONENT**

```
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) { };
}
```

**APP COMPONENT**

```
<a routerLink='./layout'>go to layout</a>
<a routerLink='./home'>go to home </a>
```

**APP ROUTING MODULE**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'layout', component: LayoutComponent }
];
```

**APP MODULE**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So, my app component is initialized. When i click on - go to home - then it redirects me to the home component.It is initialized and i see - constructor called - in the console.
But when i go on layout component after that i don't see the statements in the console.

Why this time the constructor is not initialized ?

And it happens in the opposite, if i go first to layout i see console log statements and after if i go back to app component and then go to home i see nothing.

Comment: Please share the code where and how you have registered the service?

Comment: I edited the question Vimal. Tnx for the feedback

Comment: I imported in the question also my app.module.ts file and whole test.service file

Comment: https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/are-the-angular-services-singleton/

Comment: Because you have mentioned the providedIn is "root" then only single instance of the service will be created.

Comment: Okay,which changes should i make if i want to create instance every time ?

Comment: Aren't you better of with just instantiating a normal class? Another solution would be to add a "init()" method and call that everytime you need a "new" instance. Singleton services are meant to persist, and recreating singleton services (while possible) can often be confusing. https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: If you want to initialize them separately each time you go to home and layout give it in the providers of both home-module and layout-module ( If thats what you really want)

Answer (score 2):

Your service is provided in root.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

This means that your service will be instantiated only once, it is a [singleton](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).
If you want don't want it to be a singleton, you can change the `providedIn` value to something like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: MyModule
})
```

Or directly define your service in the `providers` of your module **and** remove the `providedIn`:

**MY-MODULE**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    TestService
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

**TEST-SERVICE**

```
@Injectable()
export class TestService {}
```

Comment: Hello Tombery.I tried your solution. But again the constructor in test service is called only once ! even the root is removed from Injectable and the service is declared in the providers array

Comment: If we declare the service in the providers array in the components itself, then the constructor will be called every time,So your answer is wrong