# Typescript singleton with service parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, singleton

I would like to create a singleton from below class and use the singleton in other files as `MyClass.Instance.SomeStatus`. I checked several questions and answers on StackOverflow, but it isn't clear yet how to create a singleton which requires a service as parameter (DI). Could you explain the correct way of implementing this case? (Do I need to add `MyClass` to '`@NgModule({`' as well?)

Note: I already had a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198785/how-do-i-create-a-singleton-service-in-angular-2), but it doesn't explain the DI service parameter.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyClass {

    public SomeStatus: boolean = false;

    constructor(private _myService:MyService) {
    }

   public DoSomething(): void
   {          
        this._myService.observableEvents.subscribe(result => {
                this.SomeStatus = result;
        });
   }
}
```

**Update 1**

```
@Injectable()
export class AnotherClass{

    constructor(private _myService:MyService, private myClass:MyClass) {
    }
}
```

In the html file I use: `myClass.SomeStatus`.

Comment: If you inject `MyClass` it's already a singleton -- Angular does this for you as part of its dependency injection. You do have to declare it as a provider in a module where other injectables in the same module will inject it.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I was thinking the same, but why is the constructor called multiple times? The SomeStatus is set to false everytime, despite I earlier called the DoSomething method. (Please have a look at 'Update 1'.)

Comment: @ExplosionPills Update 1: So class x calls the DoSomething method of MyClass. AnotherClass uses, at a later point in time, the myClass object (DI). myClass.SomeStatus remains false, despite this.SomeStatus is set to true during the call of DoSomething. (Note: I already added MyClass to the providers of @NgModule).

Comment: `AnotherClass` will also have to be part of `NgModule` and it has to be injectable as well.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks for the suggesting, but unfortunately they are both @Injectable() and added to the providers section of NgModule. ('Update 1' was just pseudo code, I updated the code). For some reason, the constructor of AnotherClass is called multiple times and the SomeStatus is reset to false (as mentioned in my previous comment).

Comment: By any chance could you show us on stackblitz.com

Answer (score 0):

you can create singletons by either using the `providedIn: 'root'` flag on the service itself. **It will work, regardless whether you use other services as DI or not.**

If you use lazy loading of modules/routes you need a different approach, and can use the `.forRoot()` pattern, to ensure your service is only being initialized once. I just wrote an example that also outlines why lazy loading works differently here https://developapa.com/angular-singleton-service/