# How to Attach a Variable to $scope in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Finding angular 2 syntax is pain - everything is outdated. With that said, what is the proper way to attach variables (simple or objects) to "$scope"? (I realize the idea of controller $scope doesn't exist anymore...or controllers for that matter):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'testtag',
  templateUrl: './simplecomponent.component.html',
})

export class SimpleComponent {

  public myNumber : number = 5; 

}
```

html:

```
<div>Hi from component template! {{myNumber}}</div>
```

This code [works](http://plnkr.co/edit/eKQeZbPG0I8vJrhdep8M?p=preview). I can see "5" in my template output. HOWEVER, everything I have read seems to to say that I need to do something like `this.muNumber = 5;`. Is that for when plain javascript is used? Is `this` even relevant when using typescript? If so, how?

tl;dr: What's the proper way to do one way and two-way binding in Angular 2 as of right now? (Now that "final" Angular 2 is out).

Comment: `this` is a reference of a `Simplecomponent` (i.e) instance in the class constructor block, and `this` is always normal in both TypeScript and ECMAScript. In the global scopes, `this` refers to the global object if strict mode isn't enabled (in ES5).

Comment: I don't fully understand. I get what 'this' does in javascript and other languages, and have used it in, say, javascript services. BUT just to be absolutely clear 'this' is not used in any way when using Typescript, right? Is what I am doing the correct way to bind when using typescript?

Comment: typescript does not change the runtime semantics of javascript in any discernible way. `this` in typescript is still the same as `this` in javascript. I recommend you learn more about basic javascript and typescript before attempting to take on web frameworks.

Comment: No, you are completely wrong. `this` is still used in TypeScript. How else would you access the `myNumber` property? it isn't bound to the scope, it is bound to the instance of the class. The syntax you have there is just syntactic sugar for `this.myNumber = 5` in the constructor. In fact if you compile the TypeScript, you will see exactly this.

Comment: note angular2 hasn't got a notion of `$scope`, as such (I mean, it does under the hood I guess, but you can't access it directly). Instead you place values on the controller (similar to `controllerAs` from angular 1.x, except now the `$ctrl` is implied)

Comment: Hey Dan, read the question, like this part: "I realize the idea of controller $scope doesn't exist anymore...or controllers for that matter"

Comment: Sure, but everything else I said still applies though. By the way, stick with one way data binding, don't use two way data binding. You already have the correct way of doing one way data binding.

Comment: Find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921058/alternative-to-scope-in-angular-2-0/50969068#50969068

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the question, It seems that you want to know how you get `5` as output without using `this`?

It is printing `5` because you are directly assigning the initial value to property `myNumber` of class `SimpleComponent`. Since that is initialized with `5` it prints `5` when rendered.

If you want to fit `this` in your example this is how your component will look like

```
export class SimpleComponent {
  public myNumber : number; 
  constructor() {
    this.myNumber = 5;
  }
}
```

In short whenever you are trying to access the class property inside constructor or any function inside component you have to use `this`